# ReactJs - onclick event for each child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fire of an event when each component is clicked. Can anyone please tell me the best way to go about this? The custom method doesn't fire off at the moment. Can anyone help?

```
var MessageTypeNavigation = React.createClass({
displayName : 'MessageTypeNavigation',

// method I want to fire on each click
_clearBasket: function(){
console.log('clear basket');

},
_getPrimaryTabs: function(){
    if(this.props.hidePrimaryTabs) return [];
    var active = this.props.activeSection;

    return [
        <TabLink onClick={_clearBasket} isActive={active === 'general'} key="general" route="general-contacts" label="General" />,
        <TabLink onClick={_clearBasket} isActive={active === 'attendance'} key="attendance" route="attendance-contacts" label="Attendance" />,
        <TabLink onClick={_clearBasket}  isActive={active === 'lateness'} key="lateness" route="temp" label="Lateness" />,
        <TabLink onClick={_clearBasket}  isActive={active === 'detention'} key="detention" route="temp" label="Detention" />,
        <TabLink onClick={_clearBasket}  isActive={active === 'behaviour'} key="behaviour" route="behaviour" label="Behaviour" />,
        <TabLink onClick={_clearBasket}  isActive={active === 'achievements'} key="achievements" route="achievements" label="Achievements" />
    ];
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul className="tabs">
                    {this._getPrimaryTabs()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
},
});
```

Nested tabLink component:

```
var TabLink = React.createClass({
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
},

getTabClass: function () {
    return this.props.isActive ? "active_on" : "";
},

getLinkNode: function() {
    if (this.props.link) return <a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.label}</a>;
    return <Link to={this.props.route}>{this.props.label}</Link>;
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <li className={this.getTabClass()}>
            {this.getLinkNode()}
        </li>
    );
}
});

module.exports = TabLink;
```

Answer (score 4):

`_clearBasket` is a member of your component, not a global function. To reference it, you should use `this._clearBasket`:

```
<TabLink onClick={this._clearBasket} 
         isActive={active === 'general'} 
         key="general"  route="general-contacts" label="General" />,
```

### Edit:

`onClick` is not supported natively on custom components. It only works for dom elements. You have to implement it yourself for the `TabLink` component. You should change:

```
<li className={this.getTabClass()}>
     {this.getLinkNode()}
</li>
```

to:

```
<li className={this.getTabClass()} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
     {this.getLinkNode()}
</li>
```

Here, `onClick` is defined natively for `<li/>` elements. `this.props.onClick` is the function that you pass to `TabLink` in your `MessageTypeNavigation` component. That function, in turn is bound to `_clearBasket`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried `this.` but it still doesn't fire the onClick

Comment: Is `TabLink` a component of yours? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: If you add `onClick={this.func}` it's passed to the component as a prop `this.props.onClick`. onClick can be an event on a DOM element but will be a prop on a component. The edit above looks correct bc the <li has the onClick event which calls the passed in prop.